# mysqldump filter?

Tags: mysql

I have to dump a database from a server, transfer the .sql to a different server, and then run the following script to delete certain rows using this syntax:

```
DELETE wp_posts
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'InternalOnly' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL);
```

Is there a way I can filter the posts before dumping them? I don't want to delete them on the original server.

Answer (score 0):

In the MySQL database you want to dump, run the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts_copy LIKE wp_posts;
INSERT INTO wp_posts_copy
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE NOT(wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'InternalOnly' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL);
```

It will create the table `wp_posts_copy` with the same structure as `wp_posts`, then insert the rows you want to keep into this new table.

When using `mysqldump` to export your data, [exclude the original `wp_posts` table from the dump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table):

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=your_database.wp_posts > backup.sql
```

After importing your backup to the new server, don't forget to rename the table:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts_copy RENAME TO wp_posts;
```

Comment: Couple things, I need to dump the postmeta and term_relationships that correspond with the posts I want to keep. Also, in renaming the table after import, does it overwrite the existing wp_posts table?

Comment: Do with post_meta and term_relationships the same kind of thing I detailed in my answer, to export only the data you want to keep. The table wp_posts shouldn't exist in your target database, since you didn't export it from the source database. Renaming a table will fail if the new table already exists.

Comment: The target database is a previous clone of the source. The databases will be updated weekly so the renaming method will fail indeed. I may have to dump the source database as-is and then run the delete right after on the target.